# Slow response of titanium app in android

Tags: android, iphone, performance, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have developed an app for IOS and android with the last titanium version (4.4.0) but in android the click event for example needs a lot of time to responde and some times even a double click. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless we see the code, it is very difficult to suggest. There are some guidelines which you can follow:

1. When using tableview, provide the className property to improve performance.
2. Do not use too many view loops (one view in another and so on) and try to keep it simple.
3. Open the window once all the UI elements have been organized. This will render quickly compared to opening the window and then organizing the UI elements.
4. If performing long actions (time consuming) better to show an activity indicator to the user, suggesting that the application is performing some action.

I think the community can also add more such guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to soumya's points i am adding following

1.Never write event listeners for each row component in a window.Write one event listener then identify the originated event element by its property.
2.Apply lazy loading for images.(Load thumbnails in listing screens)
3.Always make null reference to used objects on window close